# Silverman AEC-Theorem 9.3

Tags: linear-algebra, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Can someone explain why in the last line(image 2),$T\alpha=0\implies T\alpha\beta=0$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please avoid using images in posts when possible, as they are difficult to search.

Comment: I'm sorry,I thought it would be difficult to explain the context and hence posted an image.I'll remember from next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is somewhat confusing - recall that Silverman is replacing $\beta$ with $\beta - \frac{1}{2}T(\beta) - \frac{T(\alpha \beta)}{2\alpha^2}\alpha$ in the previous line. So in the line you are asking about, this is the quantity that $\beta$ represents. For clarity I will leave $\beta$ fixed, and set $\beta' := \beta - \frac{1}{2}T\beta - \frac{T(\alpha\beta)}{2\alpha^2}\alpha$. Then the question is, why is $T(\beta') = T(\alpha \beta') = 0$?

The answer is a computation:
\begin{align*}
T(\beta') & = T(\beta) - \frac{1}{2}T\beta - \frac{T(\alpha \beta)}{2\alpha^2}\alpha \\
& = T(\beta) - \frac{1}{2}T(T(\beta)) - \frac{T(\alpha \beta)}{2\alpha^2}T(\alpha) \\
& = T(\beta) - \frac{1}{2}(2T\beta) - 0 \\
& = 0.
\end{align*}

Where we have used the following facts of our situation: the trace is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear, $T(\alpha \beta), T(\beta), \alpha^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $T(q) = 2q$ for any $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $T(\alpha) = 0$. The fact that $T(\alpha \beta') = 0$ is a similar computation.

Comment: Thank you.My brain was hurting trying to show that $T(\alpha\beta)=0$ instead of $T(\alpha\beta^{'})=0$.

Comment: I must have had the same thought when I read this proof, because I had basically what I just typed out above written in the margin of my copy of the book :). If two people had the same issue, maybe a new symbol was in order...

Comment: Haha,maybe asking Silverman to clarify in Errata,Corrections would be a better idea for future.